# Use pipenv to install pyside

Tags: pipenv, pyside2

I am using python 3.6 and pipenv 2018.05.18.

I would like to install pyside2 with pipenv, but I did not found how to do it.

I tried replacing pip with pipenv in [Qt's tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted.html) but it didn't work.

```
pipenv install --index-url=http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.11/latest pyside2 --trusted-host download.qt.io
```

This command failed.

I tried adding `http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.11/latest` as source in my Pipfile, and it didn't work either.

```
[[source]]
url = "http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.11/latest"
verify_ssl = false
name = "qt"
```

The code I added to my Pipfile for that attempt.

Do you have any ideas on how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scripts` section in `Pipfile`. For example

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"

[scripts]
install_pyside2 = "python -m pip install --index-url=http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.11/latest pyside2 --trusted-host download.qt.io"
```

Then, just run `pipenv run install_pyside2`

Comment: This works, but it does not include PySide2 in the `[packages]`. Thus, I will not be able to install it using `pipenv sync` or `pipenv install`. And it won't be recorded in the `Pipfile.lock`.

Comment: yep. it was somehow a workaround. waiting for `pipenv` supports such thing as you said in the near future.